# Can we have a timeout setting at consumer side in Spring AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Can we have a timeout setting at consumer side in Spring AMQP ,

We have a use case where AMQP message gets at consumer side

```
 @Named("TestListener")
public class TestListener implements MessageListener {

        @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
      // some error logic which got hanged the consumer thread 
    }
```

Is there any way we can timeout the consumer ( TestListener ) code so that Listener does not get hanged in Spring AMQP

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing the framework can do if a thread is "stuck" in your code.

You could inject a custom task executor, stop the container, and shut down the executor (all threads will be stopped), or you can save off the thread and interrupt is some other way.

But even interrupting the thread (with any technique) won't help if the "stuck" user code is not interruptible - such as in a tight CPU loop or waiting on a socket read.

Best solution is to fix the code that's hanging the thread.